# open directory as a project from command line intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I currently use the following command when I'm in the directory I want and I want to create a project in intellij:

`open -b com.jetbrains.intellij`

I find this alot more verbose than

`subl .`

Is there a more terse command for creating a project from the current directory (from the command line) with intellij?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an alias in your bash profile to replace that line. Something like:

`alias openij="open -b com.jetbrains.intellij"`